# Church Slavonic in German document

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, cyrillic

I am currently working on a paper about (ancient) Romanian. I would like to give some rather short (less than a page) example of an old text written with church slavonic letters. Here's my problem: how do I do that?

I've already found the churchslavonic package for XeLaTeX but I just can't get it to work properly. Also I am not sure if I can just switch from my LaTeX-"Code" to XeLaTex without ruining something else due to complications etc.

So in the following you'll find my (extensive?) preamble that mostly regulates my bibliography (my university forces us to use their weird way of doing things...).

```
%Preamble%

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showframe}

%%Tabellen%%
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

%%Codierung%%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[footnote,printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{combelow}

%%Fußnoten%%
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\mdseries\rmfamily}
\onehalfspacing
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt,font=footnotesize}
\deffootnote[1.0em]{1.0em}{1.0em}
    {\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,\enskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%%Inhaltverzeichnis%%
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}

%%Bibliographie%%
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{KonSysRum.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{references={Bibliographie}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}%
    {}{%
       \printtext[parens]{%
         \iffieldnum{edition}{\printfield[superedition]{edition}\global\clearfield{edition}}{}%
         \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}%
           {\printdateextralabel}{\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}%
       }%
      }%
}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
   {}{%
      \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
      \setunit{\addspace}%
      \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
      \clearname{editor}\newunit%
   }%
   \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
   \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+othersstrg}{\usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{bytypestrg}[2]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1type}{\bibstring{#2}}{%
    \ifbibxstring{\thefield{#1type}}%
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1type}}}{\printtext{\thefield{#1type}}}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{/}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\newcounter{SprachB}
\newcommand{\SprachB}[1]{\refstepcounter{SprachB}\label{#1}}

%Document%

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{2}

Some German text here: Deutsches Beispiel äöüß.
Church Slavonic here: ДЕРЕПТАЬ А҃ЧѢ҆Ѧ Ꙟ҆ МѸ́ЛТЕ ПЪРЦИ
А҃МЬ Ꙟ҆ ТРЕБАГЬ ША́МЬ КЪꙋТАТЬ ПЪНѪ Ѡ҃А҃МЬ А҃ФЛА҃ТЬ Ꙟ ЦА́РА
РѸМѪНѢСКѪ
```

I am forever greatful if somebody can point out an (easy) way for me to do this. Also I'm currently using OpenSuse and cannot find the churchslavonic package in their repository!

Please feel free to ask for any other additional information needed!

Comment: For a start, see [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/2693).

Comment: This is the changed code part:

`\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[footnote,printonlyused]{acronym}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{combelow}`

If I run it there is a problem with the tipa.sty: it says "Command \sups already defined" and the problemcode in tipa.sty is this:
`\newcommand{\sups}[2]{\textipa{\tipaUpperaccent[.2ex]{%
  \lower.8ex\hbox{\super{#2}}}{#1}}}`

Comment: `tipa` does not play well with fontspec :(

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimized example showing the main ingredients:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{churchslavonic}

\setmainlanguage[variant=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage{churchslavonic}

\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Old Standard}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
]

\begin{document}

Some German text here: Deutsches Beispiel äöüß.
Church Slavonic here:
\foreignlanguage{churchslavonic}{ДЕРЕПТАЬ А҃ЧѢ҆Ѧ   МѸ́ЛТЕ ПЪРЦИ
А҃МЬ   ТРЕБАГЬ ША́МЬ КЪ ТАТЬ ПЪНѪ Ѡ҃А҃МЬ А҃ФЛА҃ТЬ   ЦА́РА
РѸМѪНѢСКѪ}

\end{document}
```

You need a font that supports Church Slavonic, I used Old Standard.

Comment: thank you! this is partly what I already had tried out. There is a problem for me though: my computer displays the churchslavonic characters in my browser correctly but in my compiler (Texmaker) there are a lot of boxes all over the place. plus: it cannot find churchslavonic.sty -- I've already downloaded everything but where do I put that file? or how do I install everything automatically in OpenSuse? (sorry for these many n00b questions...)

Comment: @LajosH My usual advice is to install the full vanilla TeX Live. See [How to install vanilla TeX Live on Debian or Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/); OpenSuse is no different.

Comment: I have installed vanilla TeX Live as it is proposed in that tutorial -- still `churchslavonic.sty` cannot be found and still cannot use the tlmgr command to install it =(