# How can I get the following table to text wrap?

Tags: tables

Editing so that code should be compilable - I am listing all packages, to check for conflicts (but I don't think there should be any), and I am also leaving out the references so that you can compile without my .bib file, which shouldn't impact anything. I've commented out fontspec because it's there, but it chucked up an error with specified fonts, and you are either unlikely to have mine or they may be saved as something different.

I've tried a number of solutions, no luck. It's a very simple table (though I have more complicated ones elsewhere - I have gotten things to work before but I seem to have deleted the document, for another task).

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[overlap, CJK]{ruby}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{ot-tableau}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8, backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp, language=british]{biblatex}
\usepackage{easylist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,style=tree,abbreviations,xindy,toc]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{gb4e} %Ensure this is the last \usepackage

\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{Some of the events reported during muscular paralysis caused by curare injection.}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ll}
        \toprule
        2:11 PM: & Curare injection administered over 15 minutes.\marginpar{All events are direct quotes or paraphrases of the original report.} \\
        2:20: & Speech no longer possible. Can hear distinctly. Still able to nod head and move hands. \\
        2:22: & Subject reports by movement of head that the experience is not unpleasant. \\
        2:26: & Ability to comprehend and answer questions accurately is indicated by correctness of replies when inquiries are restated in the negative or double negative. \\
        2:45: & Subject now unable to signal response to inquiries due to complete paralysis. \\
        2:48: & Eyelids manually opened. Subject stated upon recovery that he was `clear as a bell' all this period. \\
        4:50: & Subjects is able to sit up on edge of bed. Complete subjective report dictated. \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you  post a complete, compilable, code?

Comment: Use `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{lL}` instead of `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ll}`?

Comment: Off-topic, but what do you think about `\parencites[from][1-14]{smithbrowntomangoodman1947}[cited and adapted][18-19]{psylingtraxler}` instead of the `\mkbibparens{\cites[\nopp pp.]...}`? (`\nopp pp.` in particular just looks odd.)

Comment: Done, @Bernard.

Comment: @leandriis When I do that, the table fails to print.

Comment: @moewe Yes, that does look better. The reason I have \nopp is that I frequently end up having something else in there, and I'm lazy and just wanted to memorise one keybinding.

Comment: Off-topic again: You may want to clean up your preamble a bit. Do you need all the packages you load? Do you know why you load each package? Note that `TEX program = xelatex` suggests that you compile with XeLaTeX. But with XeLaTeX you should not load `inputenc` and `fontenc` (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/). Note that with Western European languages `polyglossia` offers little to no advantage over `babel` (but `biblatex` and `csquotes` have issues detecting language variants with `polyglossia`), so I would recommend `babel`. `hyperref` and `cleveref` should usually be loaded last.

Comment: @Kartöfluvofan: If I try to compile the code you posted in your question, I get an error message 'Not in outer par mode.'  which is due to the `\marginpar` command in the table. You might want to consider loading the `marginnote` package and replace `\marginpar{` by `\marginnote{`. This will make the code compilable. Genreally, do not look at the output if you recieve an error message, but (try to) fix the error.

Comment: you have used `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ll}` `l` columns are always single line, and `tabularly` requores paragraph columsn, use `LL` not `ll`

Comment: your example produces a tex error `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

Comment: never use `\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}` with xetex

Comment: @moewe For fontenc and inputenc, that is my bad. I have been told this before, but forgot to do so. As for the packages, I usually do end up using all of them, yes, but in this case, memhfixc, blindtext, and textgreek can be removed. I often have Greek, Cyrillic, and CJK, and sometimes with other scripts such as Armenian or Devanāgarī (in some contexts these can be Romanised without the script, in others not). As an off-topic myself, I may have to write something on Luwian soon, and I've honestly no clue how I'm going to go about that. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had tried `LL` before, which failed to print, as did `lL`. However, I have rearranged and cleaned my preamble as recommended by everyone, (except for keeping polyglossia - Should I load this third to last, or is there another recommendation for how to deal with the unusual requirement for it?) and the document now compiles, with the text wrapped. I'm happy to refiddle with it again later in case anyone is simply curious as to which exact issue it was..

Comment: Mhhh, if you are writing in other languages I can't say for sure that `babel` is better than `polyglossia`. I can say that `polyglossia` development has effectively stalled and that  `babel` development has been taken up again. Furthermore you seem to be in linguistics or a related field and so I assume you only need the foreign languages for short examples/glosses and don't want to localise your document in those languages. In that case I think a modern `babel` should be good enough.

Comment: @mowe If I order as you advised, but with qtree added before gb4e, I get a 'missing number, treated as zero' and a `\begin{document}` is missing error for babel.sty - I have circumnavigated it by moving babel to be loaded sooner, which has fixed the issue, but now I am getting issues with biblatex 'Patching footnotes failed. Footnote detection will not work.'

I'll do some fiddling later, but I guessed you might immediately know of a cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabulary` requires an L C or R column to do anything useful, `l` columns are always single line, also you can not have a `\marginpar` inside a table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{book}

\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some of the events reported during muscular paralysis caused by curare injection.}

    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{lL}
        \toprule
        2:11 PM: & Curare injection administered over 15 minutes. \\
        2:20: & Speech no longer possible. Can hear distinctly. Still able to nod head and move hands. \\
        2:22: & Subject reports by movement of head that the experience is not unpleasant. \\
        2:26: & Ability to comprehend and answer questions accurately is indicated by correctness of replies when inquiries are restated in the negative or double negative. \\
        2:45: & Subject now unable to signal response to inquiries due to complete paralysis. \\
        2:48: & Eyelids manually opened. Subject stated upon recovery that he was `clear as a bell' all this period. \\
        4:50: & Subjects is able to sit up on edge of bed. Complete subjective report dictated. \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabulary}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not add the `marginnote` package in order to allow for the usage of a marginnote in the tabular?

Comment: @leandriis I have done that in my local copy. Thanks. I may change it to a footnote, which is more in line with the rest of my document, I originally formatted as a marginpar because this is how Traxler has it (I mostly use marginpars to note to myself things that are taken out of end copies...)

Comment: @leandriis partly as I had forgotten about that and partly to concentrate on removing errors and focussing on the question in the title (but yes that's a good idea:-)