# Error after adding bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors, biber

I'm writing a thesis with Texmaker and for my bibliography I work with Mendeley in combination with biber 2.12.

So far, I wrote my text and added a lot of sources with the command `\cite{example2019}.` `example2019` is one of the citation keys in Mendeley.

I have my .bib file from Mendeley and now I started to connect Mendeley with my tex-file with biber.

After running biber (Process exited normally), I get 4 errors form texmaker with the following text:

```
2 times: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ′ (U+2032)

2 times: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ′ (U+2212)
```

`U+2212` seems to be a minus. However, many of my 300+ sources have a minus.

How can I find the problems most time efficient?

PS: I use the package

> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

and I tried to convert the .bib file into utf8 with TextEdit on OS X

Comment: TeXmaker is a front-end editor, not an engine. Please tell us which TeX engine you use: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or something else?

Comment: If you're free to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, which are two unicode-aware TeX engines, the issue you're experiencing will take care of itself automatically.

Comment: I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018). I don't have XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and no experience with them.

Comment: You mention you use a Mac-based system. Do you have MacTeX installed? If so, you should have both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX at the ready.

Comment: The problem is not related with bibliography: Make a simple "Hello" document and paste this: `′` or this: `−`  and you will see the same problem. You can solve the problem replacing this characters with  `\'{}` and  `$-$` , or as commented, using xelated or lualatex (that most probably are already installed in your computer).

Comment: XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX didn't work because the configuration was wrong. I had to change the directory in the options. Now with XeLaTeX it works. However, is there anything to consider now? At a first glance I just noticed that all my letters ß are now SS.

Comment: If you use XeLaTeX you should not load `inputenc` or `fontenc`, maybe removing those packages from your preamble already helps. For more details, please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/35864. It is quite hard to give more useful advice without seeing more code (best in form of an MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), though.

Comment: Any news here? In its current form this question is unlikely to receive an answer that is correct, useful for you and also useful to future visitors. We would need to see a few problematic `.bib` entries as well as a full MWE (see my comment above). If there is no update here in due time I will vote to close this question as *unclear what you are asking*.

Comment: So far, I've just tested to take out the inputenc from my preamble. This hasn't helped yet. Starting into the new week, I will continue to work on it and read your links.

Comment: Any new developments here?

Comment: Yes, finally I've checked the whole weekend by sources. The problem was an apostrophe and minuses that looked like the normal minus. However, they were different. After replacing the minus with a new one and replacing the apostrophe, the errors disappeared.