# Adding new font to TexStudio [Mac OS]

Tags: fonts, texstudio, mac

I am using LaTex with TexStudio on MacOS Catalina.

The book I am doing now requires me to use a font that is not included in the standard package. Since then I have an `.otf` file with the font. How do I make it available for my document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Loading `fontspec` and compiling with `xelatex` is the simplest way. Does the font have a maths font version, if you have formulæ?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/4012 , i.e. the XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX answer.

Comment: @Bernard As far as I understand xelatex is another compiler (like latex) so I don't want to switch to it for the entire work: I really want to understand how to switch the fonts with latex (in the case formulas are not that useful: that is a translation of DnD 5e book, but fo the future it might be handy).

Comment: For (pdf)LaTeX, the font has to be prepared for use with latex. If it is not, it is doable, but requires quite some work. Can you say which font has to be used?

Comment: @Bernard Bookinsanity at this github repo: https://github.com/jonathonf/solbera-dnd-fonts
Though I believe the approach has to be some kind of standard?

Comment: @doncherry correct me if I'm wrong but the solution provided there is about using the other font which is already on the package. I have some files which are to be included in it ;)

Comment: @f3ss1 I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time following some of your comments. What is the "standard package" you're talking about – the LaTeX installation on your machine? And which files need to be included where? But unfortunately, I have to agree with Bernard , preparing a font for use with pdflatex is an impractical amount of work in most cases. xelatex is really not that different from pdflatex and the switch shouldn't be too hard. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/4012 .

Comment: @Bernard I've decided to give xelatex a try as it really seems I can easily switch to it. Will update the answer once I figure out how to set up the font in it ;)

Comment: Fine! Feel free to ask questions if you meet any problems.