# XeTeX logo with reversed E

Tags: xetex, logos

How do I type XeTeX logo with rotated E in XeTeX itself as can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the package `xltxtra` by issuing the command

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
```

in the preamble.  Then the controls sequence

```
\XeLaTeX
```

yields the XeLaTeX logo with a mirror reflected E.

Comment: Works fine. And the macro primitive can be given ?

Comment: @user2925716 in that package (actually in the `metalogo` package that is loaded by `xltxtra`) the macro is defined as `\Xe \kern \xl@kern@XeLaTeX@eL \LaTeX`. In turn, `\xl@kern@XeLaTeX@eL` is defined as `-.125em`. So, `\Xe`, then a small negative horizontal space, then `\LaTeX`. The `\Xe` macro is defined as an X followed by an Unicode Ǝ (if available) or a regular E in a `\reflectbox` (if Ǝ is not available).

Comment: @Marijn Could you at best give a MWE of your $\Xe$ ?

Comment: It may go without saying, but `xltxtra` can only be used with XeLaTeX. It will error when used with pdf(La)TeX and refuse to do anything with Lua(La)TeX. `xltxtra` doesn't define the logos itself, it just loads `metalogo`. `metalogo` can be used with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX if it is just loaded on its own. So there is really no need and no good reason to load `xltxtra` instead of `metalogo` if you just want the logo. ...

Comment: ... Generally people seem to advise against using `xltxtra`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex/3000#comment4339_3000.

Comment: @user2925716 the definition in the package is a bit large, but you can find it in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/metalogo/metalogo.dtx (line 518-525 and 540-614). A simpler version that does not take into account all the font checks etc. would be something like `X\kern-.125em\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\reflectbox{E}}\kern-.125em\LaTeX`. The boxes need the `graphicx` package to be loaded.

Answer (score 29):

The package to use is `metalogo` (which `xltxtra` loads and uses for the logo).

*Don't* load `xltxtra` which does also other things, mostly unwanted.

Besides, `metalogo` can be used with any engine.

You can also employ `hologo`, but `metalogo` provides functions that help to adapt the (La)TeX related logos to different fonts.

Consult the documentation of both packages for more details. In the example, I use both, but `metalogo` is normally to be preferred.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{metalogo}

\begin{document}

\texttt{hologo}: \hologo{XeTeX}

\texttt{metalogo}: \XeTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]