# Can't find Metrics for opentype font; why does XeTeX need them?

Tags: fonts, xetex, errors, opentype

I want to use an OpenType font for a document, so I'm trying to compile it with xelatex. I followed the answers on this question:

[How do I use an OpenType font with my LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46/how-do-i-use-an-opentype-font-with-my-latex-document)

However, when I try to compile it, it still gives me an error complaining it can't find the metrics file. But why does it need one? Can't I just use the .otf file without converting it?

Comment: If you are getting something like `Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found`, this actually means that XeLaTeX/`fontspec` couldn't find the `.otf` (or `.ttf`) file. It also means that you are using an old version of `fontspec`, because the current version of has a much more helpful error message.

Comment: I renamed the otf file to OpenBaskerville, put it into the document working directory, and put exactly OpenBaskerville into the "setmainfont" command. Now I'm getting this error message:

`! Undefined control sequence.
\zf@set@font@type ...onttype \zf@basefont \zf@tfm 
                                                  \or \zf@atsuitrue \ifnum \...
l.7 \setmainfont{OpenBaskerville}`

Comment: If you are referring to the file name (and not the font name for installed fonts), you should add the extension, e.g. `\setmainfont{OpenBaskerville.otf}`.

Comment: Also it seems that old versions of XeLaTeX/`fontspec` don't find fonts in the document directory (at least the version that comes shipped with Ubuntu doesn't seem to be able to do that). So you might want to upgrade to a current TeX distribution version.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question why `xelatex` needs metrics: Every typesetting system needs them to decide where to put chars on the page, where to break a line, where to break a page. Without knowledge about width, height and depth of the chars (and some other information like kerning) typesetting it not possible.

The old engines like `pdftex` needed the metrics in external files (in `tfm`s). This files had to be present at the start of the compilation. The new engines `xetex` and `luatex` are able to extract the metrics on-the-fly during the compilation from the original fonts. But naturally they must be able to find the font during compilation - and this can fail for various reasons (wrong font name, font cache not up-to-date, bugs, ...).

Without more exact informations from you (complete minimal example, exact wording of the error message, where is the font, log-file) it is difficult to say why it did fail for you.