# How do I change the default typewriter font with XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, typewriter

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46/how-do-i-use-an-opentype-font-with-my-latex-document), it is detailed how to convert a project to use TrueType or OpenType fonts by switching from LaTeX to XeLaTeX. I've successfully changed my build over to use XeTeX, but I'd like to leave the default font alone. Rather, I'd like to change the fixed width font instead.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried using `\setmonofont[<options>]{<font name>}` with `fontspec`?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, I just realized -- it's the `fontspec` package that does this rather than `XeTeX` itself. That's not obvious... http://www.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf might be useful to anyone looking in the future.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Ultimately, `fontspec` is only an interface to low-level XeTeX functions.