# kozuka gothic pro L

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I would like to use this font for LateX MikTeX distribution. How do I go about it ? I have very limited experience with using different fonts or changing fonts.

Is this font available ? if not, I would be very grateful for any other input.

Comment: Related [How do I use an OpenType font with my LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46/15717)

Answer (score 2):

You can use fonts that are installed in your operating system with XeTeX. The easiest way to load these fonts into LaTeX is with the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package. Here is a minimal document demonstrating this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Kozuka Gothic Pro L}

\begin{document}
This is some text in Kozuka Gothic Pro.
\end{document}
```

For more information on `fontspec`, see its [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf).

*This question has already been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46/24113).*