# Using Lato Light Font Throughout a Document

Tags: fonts, graphics, pdftex

The command for using the lato light font is given to be

```
\fontseries{l}\selectfont
```

but this command produces no change to my document when compiled with `pdflatex`.

I would like to use the light version of Lato as the default font for my entire document.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it an `.otf` or `.ttf` font? Use `xelatex` and see [How do I use an OpenType font with my LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46/5764)

Comment: When are you issuing that command? Make sure you issue it *after* `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you say you're compiling with `pdflatex`, I assume you're using the `lato` package, so you can just set the default weight `\mddefault` to light:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{lato}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\renewcommand{\mddefault}{l}% switch default weight to light

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can you add math support though? It seems that adding \usepackage{mathastext} after \renewcommand{\mddefault}{l} does not give the desired result.

Comment: @uknown: if I add `\usepackage{mathastext}` after `\renewcommand{\mddefault}{l}` in my answer's code snippet, I get what I expect. What's the problem you have with the result ?

Comment: The problem is that by doing so, not all the math characters are in light mode e.g. numbers remain default while greek letters are light, etc.

Comment: @uknown: works perfectly for me (all glyphs from lato are light). Perhaps a version problem? Is your distribution up to date? You should ask a new question to get help on where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 6):

On the other hand, if you have `Lato.ttf` or `Lato.otf` installed and want to use them, here is a way. Use `xelatex` or `lualatex` for compiling the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato Light}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't have `Lato` installed, download a free version from [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lato) and install.

Comment: Very useful link to fontsquirrel.

Comment: thank you!  i'd really rather use pdflatex though.  unless, is there a good way to enable small caps in lualatex?