# Pros and Cons XeTeX vs pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, xetex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is XeTeX exactly and why should I use it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/what-is-xetex-exactly-and-why-should-i-use-it)

I have been using LaTeX for a while now and compiling via `pdflatex` on my Mac.  I have recently started to want more control over fonts, which has led me to look into XeTeX.

What are the pros and cons of XeTeX versus regular LaTeX, with special emphasis on the preparation of scientific or technical documents (i.e. verbatim blocks of code, and use of ams packages)?

Comment: I feel like this has been answered [already](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/what-is-xetex-exactly-and-why-should-i-use-it), but not exactly in this form, I guess.

Comment: @TH.  Too close for my taste: this is a big-list version of [Xetex ... why should I use it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/what-is-xetex-exactly-and-why-should-i-use-it).  Voting to close.

Comment: I'd agree: not voting of course as I'm a moderator :-)

Comment: Yep - you're right, at least somewhat.  For what it's worth I didn't come across the ' What is XeTeX...' question when searching or writing my question.  It doesn't have the best title if it is going to serve as the communities what's up with XeTeX question of choice.  Also, the question on 'Frequently loaded packages:  Differences...' is more about compatibility which isn't the nature of this question.  A really well fleshed out breakdown of these types of issues on here would be a great addition, whether it is done via this question or not.

Comment: It's also very similar to an earlier question of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3094/1035

Comment: I've closed it.  I'd prefer to keep such information in one place.  That it didn't come up when you searched is now fixed as this question will come up and direct to that one!  If there is something missing from that question, it would be better to ask a focussed question asking specifically for the missing information - a bit like Mateus' question does.  I don't think that another general question will draw answers given that the other question already exists.