# Is it possible to produce a PDF with un-copyable text?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, drm

Is it possible to produce a PDF with un-copyable text? I mean, when you want to copy text from the PDF, you can't copy it or what you copy is nonsense characters.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. (Well, sort of -- you could always convert to an image and OCR.) Is it a good idea? No. We must push back against the forces of OCR and commercialism, and push for the causes of open access, searchability, and software freedom. If those who favor open source software don't, no one will.

Comment: IMHO, it is never a good idea to prevent other people from copying texts in a PDF file through techniques. If we must do such things, don't convert the texts to a image (vector or bitmap). Besides loss of quality, the result file may be very large.

Comment: In addition, you'll do a huge disservice to blind people (though I guess PDF's aren't very accessible even in the best of cases).

Comment: @frabjous @Leo i am a civil engineer. i provide design documents to client and other design office. for some important documents, e.g., foundation loads, my german colleague produces image for some key values which means it is un-copyable. he produces the document by micro soft word. i prefer to tex. this is why i want to know if it is possible to make a un-copyable pdf.

Comment: I still don't understand what the motive is. If you trust your clients with this information, then you're going to have to trust them not to copy it. But if you're looking to convert your document to an image, that's very easily done (e.g., with dvipng, or ghostscript). But remember, images can be OCRed.

Comment: @frabjous my german colleague did in this way. i don't know why. they did it in winword. i use tex. so i want to know if it could be done in tex. this is why i ask this question. you mention "images can be OCRed". i know very little about ocr. does it mean, even for image, it can still be cracked by ocr?

Comment: "Cracked" isn't the right word. OCR = Optical Character Recognition. It takes an image, analyzes it to try to recognize letter shapes, and then outputs text. Of course, they could always retype what you've written, but that's usually faster.

Comment: @warem: No, it's not possible. All you need to break it is a thing called "a typist".

Comment: A use case that comes to my mind is to push back on services like turnitin.com which use my data to make money. I don't allow my documents to be used in that way thus I want to produce a document that either contains no copyable text, scrambled text or a defined text but still keep a printable document.

Comment: Use `XeTeX` to at least get some "nonsense characters" http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49794/27721

Comment: I have used OCR in the past to get recognizable text from scanned books, with a couple of clicks. Works like a charm with scanned books, will work even better with a "locked" pdf document.

Comment: Oh, just seen [this: you don't need a typist any more.](http://allthingsd.com/20130906/how-a-man-in-austria-used-legos-to-hack-amazons-kindle-e-book-security/#)

Comment: Another use case: you show source code to students during a presentation, and you'd like them to try at least once to understand the code on their own instead of simply copy-pasting it to a file ;-)

Comment: @FrederickNord I am not sure that turnitin will permit you to upload documents unless it can digest them. At least, by default, it tries not to allow this. (But I haven't tried with a PDF which is an image.) The reason for this is that obviously it cannot then check the work for plagiarism. (So there isn't much point in using it if students are allowed to upload document formats it can't digest since any canny plagiarist will ensure they upload indigestible work.)

Comment: Last time I tried it worked fine.

Comment: I think this has its uses. For example when distributing a PDF with lots of personal info. (Say a kind of address book.) The PDF goes to a large group of people. If by chance it ends up on the internet, then crawlers and bots can't (easily) read the PDF. From a privacy perspective, I think this a good.

Comment: I agree with jmc. There is absolutely value in doing this. For instance, I want to publicly post the PDF of my resume to LinkedIn, but I don't want spambots to harvest my email address and phone number. In this case, I want these bits to be unparseable by anyone other than humans.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Besides converting all texts to images, one method as I know, is to destroy the Cmaps of the fonts. We can use `cmap` package and a special cmap file for this purpose. This cmap file is generated inside the VerbatimOut environment.

(Warning: it does not make much sense to produce un-copyable PDF. OCR is very easy today.)

```
% pdflatex is required
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{VerbatimOut}{ot1.cmap}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 Resource-CMap
%%DocumentNeededResources: ProcSet (CIDInit)
%%IncludeResource: ProcSet (CIDInit)
%%BeginResource: CMap (TeX-OT1-0)
%%Title: (TeX-OT1-0 TeX OT1 0)
%%Version: 1.000
%%EndComments
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (TeX)
/Ordering (OT1)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /TeX-OT1-0 def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00> <7F>
endcodespacerange
8 beginbfrange
<00> <01> <0000>
<09> <0A> <0000>
<23> <26> <0000>
<28> <3B> <0000>
<3F> <5B> <0000>
<5D> <5E> <0000>
<61> <7A> <0000>
<7B> <7C> <0000>
endbfrange
40 beginbfchar
<02> <0000>
<03> <0000>
<04> <0000>
<05> <0000>
<06> <0000>
<07> <0000>
<08> <0000>
<0B> <0000>
<0C> <0000>
<0D> <0000>
<0E> <0000>
<0F> <0000>
<10> <0000>
<11> <0000>
<12> <0000>
<13> <0000>
<14> <0000>
<15> <0000>
<16> <0000>
<17> <0000>
<18> <0000>
<19> <0000>
<1A> <0000>
<1B> <0000>
<1C> <0000>
<1D> <0000>
<1E> <0000>
<1F> <0000>
<21> <0000>
<22> <0000>
<27> <0000>
<3C> <0000>
<3D> <0000>
<3E> <0000>
<5C> <0000>
<5F> <0000>
<60> <0000>
<7D> <0000>
<7E> <0000>
<7F> <0000>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
%%EndResource
%%EOF
\end{VerbatimOut}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: your method worked. thank you. but if i change `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}`, it didn't work.

Comment: i just found if i didn't define `12pt` at the beginning, then defined a newcommand to set the default font size later, your method worked now. i don't why. on the other hand, your method works for the whole text, is it possible to just work part of text?

Comment: `resetfonts` doesn't work for `12pt`. You can follow `cmap.sty` to undefine more predefined fonts. I have no much time.

Comment: thank you for your instruction. i added some font size into the definition of `resetfonts`, then it worked now.

Comment: That method does not work me. My evince allows me happily to copy and paste the text. Also `pdftotext` extracts all the available text. So this method does not work.

Comment: About your comment on OCR, `"OCR is very easy today."`: In languages other than `English`, it is not *that* easy. Moreover, latex is mostly used for mathematical type-setting, is a good OCR is good enough to understand mathematical symbols, subscripts etc? Hyper-links will not also work here.

Comment: @pushpen.paul: AFAIK, Chinese OCR is quite easy today. For mathematical typesetting, usually you cannot copy/search the formulas in the PDF files -- you don't even need to do any trick for that.

Comment: Actually, @LeoLiu, in my language, `Bengali`, there are only a handful of discrete attempts to make an OCR; and non of them is at least _moderate_,to the best of my knowledge. You are right about mathematical things.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me: text can still be copied in Mac OS X Preview.

Comment: For me too, this solution don't work.

Comment: @LeoLiu There is absolutely lots of value in doing this. For instance, I want to publicly post the PDF of my resume to LinkedIn, but I don't want spambots to harvest my email address or phone number. In this case, I want these bits to be unparseable by anyone other than humans.

Comment: Sometimes TeX already generate broken font for some reason, so knowledge about CMap can help recovering them more accurately than OCR (although unfortunately as far as I know there's no such program that does it yet). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41698/250119

Answer (score 32):

**Luatex** allows manipulating fonts in the `define_font` callback.
Luaotfload facilitates this even more with an extra hook it installs
right after the font loader has finished its job: the
`luaotfload.patch_font` callback.
Normally it is used for serious and constructive tasks like setting a
couple font dimensions or ensuring backward compatibility in the data
structures.
Of course, it can also be abused for dirty hacks like disabling copy
and paste.

At the point where the `patch_font` callback is applied, the font is
already defined and ready to use.
All necessary tables are created and put in a place where Luatex
expects them.
Among these is the `characters` table that holds preprocessed
information about the glyphs.
In the below code we modify the `tounicode` field of each glyph so
that it maps to some random location within the printable ASCII range.
Note that this does not affect the shape and metrics of the glyph since
those are unrelated to the actual codepoint.
As a consequence, the PDF will contain legible text that cannot be
copied.

Package file `obfuscate.lua`:

```lua
packagedata = packagedata or { }

local mathrandom    = math.random
local stringformat  = string.format

--- this is the callback by means of which we will obfuscate
--- the tounicode values so they map to random characters of
--- the printable ascii range (between 0x21 / 33 and 0x7e / 126)

local obfuscate = function (tfmdata, _specification)
  if not tfmdata or type (tfmdata) ~= "table" then
    return
  end

  local characters = tfmdata.characters
  if characters then
    for codepoint, char in next, characters do
      char.tounicode = stringformat ([[%0.4X]], mathrandom (0x21, 0x7e))
    end
  end
end

--- we also need some functions to toggle the callback activation so
--- we can obfuscate fonts selectively

local active = false

packagedata.obfuscate_begin = function ()
  if not active then
    luatexbase.add_to_callback ("luaotfload.patch_font", obfuscate,
                                "user.obfuscate_font", 1)
    active = true
  end
end

packagedata.obfuscate_end = function ()
  if active then
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback ("luaotfload.patch_font",
                                     "user.obfuscate_font")
    active = false
  end
end
```

Usage demonstration:

```
%% we will need these packages
\input luatexbase.sty
\input luaotfload.sty

%% for inspecting the pdf with an ordinary editor
\pdfcompresslevel0
\pdfobjcompresslevel0

%% load obfuscation code
\RequireLuaModule {obfuscate}

%% convenience macro
\def \packagecmd #1{\directlua {packagedata.#1}}

%% the obfuscate environment, mapping to Lua functions that enable and
%% disable tounicode obfuscation
\def \beginobfuscate {\packagecmd {obfuscate_begin ()}}
\def \endobfuscate   {\packagecmd {obfuscate_end   ()}}

%%···································································%%
%% Demo
%%···································································%%

%% firstly, load some fonts. within the “obfuscate” environment all
%% fonts will get their cmaps scrambled ...

\beginobfuscate

  \font \mainfont   = "file:Iwona-Regular.otf:mode=base"
  \font \italicfont = "file:Iwona-Italic.otf:mode=base"

\endobfuscate

%% ... while fonts defined outside will have the mapping intact

\font \boldfont       = "file:Iwona-Bold.otf:mode=base"
\font \bolditalicfont = "file:Iwona-BoldItalic.otf:mode=base"

%% now we can use them in our document like any ordinary font

\mainfont
obfuscated text before {\italicfont     obfuscated too} and after \par
obfuscated text before {\boldfont       not obfuscated} and after \par
obfuscated text before {\bolditalicfont not obfuscated} and after \par

\bye
```

Result in PDF viewer:

[image: result displayed]

Contrast this with the output of `pdftotext`:

```
\rf2yC'I_J I_dI r_f\{_ 9;H`bp<<L& <99 '5J 'fI_{
\rf2yC'I_J I_dI r_f\{_ not obfuscated '5J 'fI_{
\rf2yC'I_J I_dI r_f\{_ not obfuscated '5J 'fI_{
```

But please forget about all this immediately and never obfuscate a
production text -- don’t be mean to your readers!

---

**EDIT**
Because the generous karma donor specifically asked for a Context
solution, I’ll throw that one in as a bonus.
It is a good deal more elegant since it relies on the *font goodies*
mechanism that allows applying postprocessors to specific fonts which
can afterwards be used just like common font features.

```
\startluacode

local mathrandom    = math.random
local stringformat  = string.format

--- create a postprocessor

local obfuscate = function (tfmdata)
  fonts.goodies.registerpostprocessor (tfmdata, function (tfmdata)
    if not tfmdata or type (tfmdata) ~= "table" then
      return
    end

    local characters = tfmdata.characters
    if characters then
      for codepoint, char in next, characters do
        char.tounicode = stringformat ([[%0.4X]], mathrandom (0x21, 0x7e))
      end
    end
  end)
end

--- now register as a font feature

fonts.handlers.otf.features.register {
  name         = "obfuscate",
  description  = "treat the reader like a piece of garbage",
  default      = false,
  initializers = {
    base     = obfuscate,
    node     = obfuscate,
  }
}

\stopluacode

%%···································································%%
%% demonstration
%%···································································%%

%% we can now treat the obfuscation postprocessor like any other
%% font feature

\definefontfeature [obfuscate] [obfuscate=yes]

\definefont [mainfont]   [file:Iwona-Regular.otf*obfuscate]
\definefont [italicfont] [file:Iwona-Italic.otf*obfuscate]

\definefont [boldfont]       [file:Iwona-Bold.otf]
\definefont [bolditalicfont] [file:Iwona-BoldItalic.otf]


\starttext

  \mainfont
  obfuscated text before {\italicfont     obfuscated too} and after \par
  obfuscated text before {\boldfont       not obfuscated} and after \par
  obfuscated text before {\bolditalicfont not obfuscated} and after \par

\stoptext
```

Comment: I'll see your obfuscator and raise you by some free OCR package :D

Comment: @Mark Never mind OCR, this is deterministic 1 to 1 character mapping: t=I, e=_, x=d, etc. A few minutes with a document could produce a `sed` substitution expression for all the changed glyphs. Pipe your `pdftotext` into that and you have a 100% fix. All this does is waste both author (and reader) time without actually solving anything but making them feel like they have. Poor-mans-DRM is even worse than the real thing.

Comment: @Caleb I disagree with your view on this. There is absolutely value in doing this. For instance, I want to publicly post the PDF of my resume to LinkedIn, but I don't want spambots to harvest my email address or phone number. In this case, I want these bits to be unparseable by anyone other than humans.

Comment: Can you give a real-world demo of how to use this with lualatex and, e.g., `article` document class? I don't know how to use it :-(

Comment: @bonanza Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485522/how-to-obfuscate-text-in-latex-class work for you?

Comment: I see many complaints that there is no value in doing this and it should never be done, yet not all pdfs are created for production and distribution where they will be immediately hacked. For instance, I am programming instructor. I occasionally want to give my beginning students sample code that they have to type out in order to learn basic programming. Some of the code can be modified to answer homework problems. I do not want them simply copying and pasting the code, so I give obfuscated pdfs. If a student were to un-obfuscate it and I found out, great! I'd say good job and make a new one.

Answer (score 22):

## Remarks

I use a little script, which converts all my fonts to paths. The script uses the first parameter as input of a `.pdf`-file and writes the output to a file with the same name and the extension`-rst.pdf`

You need [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) for my script to run.

## Implementation

Runs on `bash`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

GS=/usr/bin/gs

$GS -sDEVICE=ps2write       -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=-        -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE "$1"       -c quit | ps2pdf - > "${1%%.*}-rst.pdf"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Output written to ${1%%.*}-rst.pdf"
else
    echo "There were errors. See the output."
fi
```

use ps2write (instead of pswrite) these days as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546677/embedfonts-complains-about-unknown-device-pswrite).

## Result

> [image]

Comment: No match for OCR though :D

Comment: Well I guess, that there is no way to trick any OCR Software (without adding things, like striking/crossing the text out), because the OCR Software can read, what you can read.

Comment: Specialised OCR software can break some types of CAPTCHA too... You can use excessive striking/deforming/noise to harden your file against this, but then humans won't be able to read half of it either!

Comment: Your script works, but (at least on my files, which are slides produced with beamer) produces very pale and large files. It also takes a relatively long time to finish.

Comment: Do I need to locate the file that I want to convert at the first line of the script. I tried with script command 
sudo bash .script_file_name 
It generate -rst.pdf file. Please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: @Trickster You run it like `bash script_name "path/to/pdf/file"`. You don't need `sudo` as no additional privileges are needed for this script.

Comment: What is the image supposed to show? I'm not sure the blank guarantees anything...

Comment: Ghostscript has been improved and can do it on its own nowadays, [gs -o file-with-outlines.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite file.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798374/857727).

Comment: Note that using the method in this answer will make it slightly rasterized, while using `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite` doesn't.

Comment: Can you remove only specific fonts? For example if you want to hide only some parts of the doc, you would use a specific font just for these parts.

Answer (score 21):

You can disable the copying of text with the help of PDF encryption. With it you can also disable other things like printing.

You need to use an external PDF tool like `pdftk` or of course the full version of Adobe Acrobat to encrypt the PDF.

Comment: However, encryption doesn't work for (almost all as I know) non-Adobe PDF readers.

Comment: I often use a certain open-source reader (with just one line of code commented out) to bypass PDF protection and passwords.  Anyone familiar with SourceForge, GIT and MAKE can easily roll their own in a matter of minutes too.

Comment: @MarkKCowan I know of other, less sophisticated (if but also effective) ways than what you describe; out of sheer curiousity (though that curiousity is not *that* large that I'd try and patch it myself): Could you provide more verbose details or a link to a commented (indicating the commented-out line) GIT ? - sry about the overuse of (brackets); I'm drunk.

Comment: It was a long time ago when I built it.  I think it was a Java application, there was one particular line which was a const "final boolean <something> = <somevalue>;" which related to password protection.  Apparently, Ubuntu was the only distro where the password protection had been enabled, so I flipped that boolean and recompiled to produce a binary which didn't bother with the whole password fake-DRM stuff.  Strictly speaking, I changed the value of a boolean constant, rather than commenting out a line.

Comment: Okular has a user setting which determines whether it recognises DRM or not...

Comment: And Evince etc. etc.

Answer (score 12):

If content can be viewed, it can be copied.
No matter what encryption and restrictions are used, at some point the content must be put out in plain view in order for it to be of any use.
This is probably true of all digital content and most physical content larger than the nanoscale...

For example, a PDF:

- Rasterisation: Printscreen => OCR
- Any protection: Re-type it out
- Content protection: Modified build of an open-source reader

Web content:

- Right-click popup: Opera=>Prevent page receiving content menu events
- Right-click popup: "Menu" button on any modern keyboard
- Flash: Download the SWF file, decompile it using free software
- View page source, use Chrome/Opera/Firefox debugger to get URL of desired content

Audio (e.g. HDCP):

- Headphones socket on TV => line-in socket on PC
- Solder to tap into preamplifier => line-in socket on PC

Video (e.g. HDCP):

- Many, many options...  A quick google search will show you.

Encrypted content on someone's laptop/pendrive:

- Digital brute force: brute-force cracking of the encryption key
- Physical brute force: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png

Comment: One of these is not like the others. The last item is both wrong and a different scenario from your premise.

Comment: A possible use case is to prevent e.g. the line numbers of a piece of code to be copied.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is: Yes.
There is a way described here: http://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/corner/Obfuscated_PDF

But it looks tedious and doesn't use pdflatex. The method, however, is described as being portable to PDF. It involves changing glyphs of a font and other dirty things that get you bad dreams.

I didn't find a method described for directly PDF let alone something automated for pdflatex. I'll happily buy you a beverage of your choice if you implement it :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Ghostscript for that. Just create your PDF as usual and run

```
 gs -o output.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite input.pdf
```

**Please note** that you cannot prevent people from using **OCR** software like Tesseract on the output. I'm not even sure if making the PDF an image prevents todays search engines from indexing your PDF. The file size increases, people with eye problems will have a harder time. So think hard if you really want to harm your readers like that.

Comment: However, no pdf viewer seems to respect that setting

Answer (score 3):

You can use ImageMagick to convert the pdf to an image pdf.
Running 

`convert file1.pdf file2.pdf`
 
will create a pdf called `file2.pdf` which is about the same size as the input pdf but since its an image, the text cannot be selected. There is a notable decrease in quality though

Comment: there are several parameters to `convert` that improve output quality.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `gswin32` only make a pdf after change the format to ps:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32.exe" -sDEVICE=ps2write -r9000 
-dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.ps input_insecure.pdf
```

Now translate to pdf with secure mode 4 (only read and print):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r9000 
-dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 
-dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -sOwnerPassword=null -dEncryptionR=3 
-dKeyLength=40 -dPermissions=4 -sOutputFile=OUTPUT_secure.pdf output.ps
```

On a unix-based system, you can probably type `gswin32` instead of `"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32.exe"`.

Comment: I tried your solution and https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/c268f5c356421a82ed31417837c27d03 - it seems like none of my PDF viewers respect this permission

Answer (score 1):

Use `XeTeX` to at least get some "nonsense characters", see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49794/27721) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49502/small-caps-old-style-numbers-and-some-ligatures-produce-odd-symbols-in-pdf-cop).

Though this would obviously be just a nuisance for most cases/users (which can be avoided using `LuaLaTeX` instead), depending on what you are trying to achieve compiling with `XeTeX` *may* prove to add at least *some* value to your solution...

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution:
I'm using `ocrmypdf` (https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF) which behind the scenes uses `Tesseract`, and I force it to OCR my pdf in a language with a very different alphabet (e.g. Korean). This will effectively replace my text content with none-sense, because of the differences in alphabets.

```
ocrmypdf --force-ocr -l kor input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: Nice, the only thing, however, is that coloured texts is rendered as a dotted pattern (see https://imgur.com/wtdXk5A, where the text was dark blue).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has mentioned you can use expensive paid for security to try and stop screen grabbing. (You use a dedicated coded viewer and that monitors the system for known applications)

However as I have seen that defeated both by above mentioned "Typist" technique and also seen it cannot detect some "freeware" screen OCR grabbers, It would be pointless for anyone else to have given this as a valid answer.

Especially if they have a camera phone with OCR app or can hit the alternative "PrintScreen" button.

Please buy more snake oil it keeps the PDF industry thriving.