# PDF Security/Encryption with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, security, drm

I was wondering whether it is possible to protect pdf files (e.g. control printing/copying/... access) with LuaLaTeX **without using third-party software** like [QPDF](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/) or those listed in the [pdfcrypt](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrypt) package.

Some older [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237093) says its possible with the `\special` command, but its example uses XeTeX and while testing with LuaLaTeX its not really working as expected. They indeed say probably there is no equivalent for LuaLaTeX:

```latex
\special{pdf:encrypt ownerpw (abc) userpw (xyz) length 128 perm 2052}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Is it maybe possible with LuaLaTeXs backend primitives like `\pdfextension`?

I'd be grateful if someone can show me a MWE if its possible with LuaLaTeX only.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Relevant discussion at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19797/pdf-with-un-copyable-text-in-lualatex?rq=1  After you encrypt your pdf, send it to me and I will OCR it and decrypt it!

Comment: @YiannisLazarides "Encrypt" means "set a password for the PDF" in this context, not "prevent the text to be copied".

Comment: @Dave I don't think it's possible, nevertheless, you may be happy with workarounds such as using an external tool but call it within the LaTeX run itself, such as seen in [compiling - Can TeX post-process the PDF it produces? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21310/can-tex-post-process-the-pdf-it-produces/705583#705583)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [@user202729](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/250119/user202729) I was able to automate securing/encrypting pdf files via [QPDF](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/) ([Documentation](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/)) within LuaLaTeX.

During post-processing of the PDF in the *wrapup_run* phase, the output directory is read via Lua's pattern matching:

```lua
local outdir = nil
for i = 0, #arg, 1 do
    if string.find(arg[i], "%-+output%-d[irectory]*%=?%s?") then
        outdir = string.gsub(arg[i], "%-+output%-d[irectory]*%=?%s?", "")
    end
end
```

**Note**: I cannot say exactly whether all argument formats are covered by this, at least all formats that [@user202729](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/250119/user202729) has posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653148/293060) are recognised.

QPDF is then executed with the desired arguments:

```lua
os.execute((outdir ~= nil and "cd " .. outdir .. " &&" or "") .. "qpdf " .. tex.jobname .. ".pdf --encrypt userpw ownerpw 256 --accessibility=y --assemble=y --extract=y --form=y --modify-other=y --print=full -- " .. tex.jobname .. "_secure.pdf")
```

**Full MWE (Windows 10)**:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("wrapup_run", function()
        local outdir = nil
        for i = 0, #arg, 1 do
            if string.find(arg[i], "%-+output%-d[irectory]*%=?%s?") then
                outdir = string.gsub(arg[i], "%-+output%-d[irectory]*%=?%s?", "")
            end
        end
        os.execute((outdir ~= nil and "cd " .. outdir .. " &&" or "") .. "qpdf " .. tex.jobname .. ".pdf --encrypt userpw ownerpw 256 --accessibility=y --assemble=y --extract=y --form=y --modify-other=y --print=full -- " .. tex.jobname .. "_secure.pdf")
    end, "Callback to secure pdf")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```