# How i can tranform my PDF file so that it will not be readable by the system

Tags: pdf, texstudio

I see one document (PDF), when i try to copy its text (one paragraph), it gives me as:

> Theunderlyingproblemisageneralmodelselectionproblem,wherewehavetocompare
>   twomodelsM1andM2suchthatmodelM1isevaluatedwithrespecttothetrainingsetD1,
>   whilemodelM2isevaluatedwithrespecttothetrainingsetD2.Ofcourse,forthisproblem
>   tobemeaningful,weassumethatD1andD2arebothsampledfromthesameunderlying
>   distribution.

That mean it is in combined form (removed spaces) so that we can extract individual words directly.

Now, i would also like to transform my personal writings (pdf) in Latex so that it will not be readable by the system. If some one copy its text and past in other editor, then it will removes inter word spaces.  Or any text reading software could not read it.

For example: if some one copy above paragraph from my PDF file and past in another editor, then it will be looks like:

> Now,iwouldalsoliketotransformmypersonalwritings (pdf) in
>   Latexsothatitwillnotbereadablebythesystem.Ifsomeonecopy
>   itstextandpastinothereditor,thenitwillremovesinterword
>   spaces.Oranytextreadingsoftwarecouldnotreadit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Can you describe your workflow and what result you would like to achieve?

Comment: I think now it is more clear.

Comment: OCR software will always be capable to read your PDF.

Comment: Does this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11307/15925 help you?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes you are right.