# Deny copy in pdf

Tags: copy-paste

I want to create a pdf file with non-copyable properties for text.
It can encrypt text to some code (such as ASCII), deny copy paragraph. 
I found some examples on web about this. I must use font 13pt with Times New Roman for my thesis, so I use package `extbook`, `type1cm`, `mathptmx`. When I use these pacakges, I can't encrypt my text to deny copy.
Please help me solve this problem.

I see you marked this question already answered. I know this answer but it can't solve my problem. I must use `extbook` and some more package. And this answer not working. Please see my code:

```
\documentclass[13pt]{extbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}  
\usepackage{type1cm} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
      paperwidth=210mm,
      paperheight=297mm,
      left=35mm,right=20mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{VerbatimOut}{OT1.cmap}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 Resource-CMap
%%DocumentNeededResources: ProcSet (CIDInit)
%%IncludeResource: ProcSet (CIDInit)
%%BeginResource: CMap (TeX-OT1-0)
%%Title: (TeX-OT1-0 TeX OT1 0)
%%Version: 1.000
%%EndComments
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (TeX)
/Ordering (OT1)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /TeX-OT1-0 def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00> <7F>
endcodespacerange
8 beginbfrange
<00> <01> <0000>
<09> <0A> <0000>
<23> <26> <0000>
<28> <3B> <0000>
<3F> <5B> <0000>
<5D> <5E> <0000>
<61> <7A> <0000>
<7B> <7C> <0000>
endbfrange
40 beginbfchar
<02> <0000>
<03> <0000>
<04> <0000>
<05> <0000>
<06> <0000>
<07> <0000>
<08> <0000>
<0B> <0000>
<0C> <0000>
<0D> <0000>
<0E> <0000>
<0F> <0000>
<10> <0000>
<11> <0000>
<12> <0000>
<13> <0000>
<14> <0000>
<15> <0000>
<16> <0000>
<17> <0000>
<18> <0000>
<19> <0000>
<1A> <0000>
<1B> <0000>
<1C> <0000>
<1D> <0000>
<1E> <0000>
<1F> <0000>
<21> <0000>
<22> <0000>
<27> <0000>
<3C> <0000>
<3D> <0000>
<3E> <0000>
<5C> <0000>
<5F> <0000>
<60> <0000>
<7D> <0000>
<7E> <0000>
<7F> <0000>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
%%EndResource
%%EOF
\end{VerbatimOut}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Please help me , I really want to know how to get it.

Comment: Note that this request (from a pure (La)TeX point of view), might be viewer-specific. An external tool like the [PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can do alter the user permissions.

Comment: See [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text)

Comment: No, I don't want to use pdf tool. Because we can remove deny easy by some sofware. It's here I want to ecrypt make it can't copy. When you copy and past, the result is some strange symbols.