# PDFLaTeX encoding problem

Tags: pdftex, pdf, input-encodings, copy-paste

I am generating a pdf file with PDFLaTeX. The content of the pdf looks well at a first glance. However if I try to copy and paste the text to somewhere else the text look like this:
❉✐❡ ▼❡♥❣❡ ❛♥ ■♥❢♦r♠❛t✐♦♥❡♥ ✉♥❞ ❘❡ss♦✉r❝❡♥ ✐♠ ■♥t❡r♥❡t ✇ä❝❤st ❢♦rt❧❛✉❢❡♥❞✳
Instead of how it should looks like:
*Die Menge an Informationen und Ressourcen im Internet wächst fortlaufend.*

Likewise it is not possible to search inside the pdf document. It seems that there is something wrong with the encoding.

*EDIT*
I found that this happens because I am using the template dissonline:
http://files.d-nb.de/dissonline/dissonline_latex_ver_2.1.zip

There is a documentclass *DissOnlineLatex* which leads to this problem, but I am still not know how to fix it.

Comment: Please post an MWE and/or a link to the .pdf in question.

Comment: Try [`cmap`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cmap/README).

Comment: Mmm I think that should be something with the codification of your document, what are you using for type with inputenc, and what are you using with fontenc for the PDF. Finally sometimes the pdfviewer fails to copy the characters. But we need a MWE as Igmar suggested.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use the `DissOnlineLatex` document class? Is switching to something more common (and, perhaps, better documented) an option?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: This might be intentional: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11307/6865