# Printing user name at PDF and other stuff

Tags: pdf, watermark, drm

I'm finishing a pdf book and I'm gonna sell it. Trying to avoid keep it downloadable to anyone, I'd like to print in every single page the name of the person who bought it, like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

And, how do I block someone to use ctrl+c at my pdf document?

Comment: There are many 'watermark' packages; search CTAN for `watermark`, `xwatermark`, `eso-pic`, `background`, ....  I don't think most dedicated thieves will care much about whose name is on the physical page or the metadata, however.  Regarding 'uncopyable' output, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11307/8528); there are some clever-seeming answers.  But remember that nothing will be foolproof: someone can always at the very least take screenshots of the page(s).

Comment: Or they can always use an old-fashioned device known as a "secretary" to type it all out again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know how to make it difficult to copy text from a PDF fike, however, here is an easy way to put the purchaser's name onto each page:

[image]

This is using the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package, which is one of the options suggested by Jon in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{position={0,0},anchor=left,angle=90,scale=1.2,pages=all,
                 opacity=1, contents={Purchased by Julie Citizen}}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum
  \lipsum
  \lipsum
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

It is easy to inject the background setup lines into a latex document using a shell script - in fact, I use a variation on this idea to display git commit data on pdf files that are generated directly by git.