# How to protect a PDF generated via LaTeX

Tags: pdf, printing, copy-paste, drm

I've seen several questions similar to this one, but mine is how I can protect my PDF:

1. Extract contents.
2. Print.
3. And, eventually, customize all the meta tag.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to protect the PDF *against* extracting contents, printing and customizing the meta tags?

Comment: Exactly @egreg. I would like use LaTeX for generating text books for my students and... I know that this protection isn't very effective, but important for same contents (e.g., exercises, solutions).

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text ?

Comment: btw: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Not a TeX comment but FWIW: twenty year olds will un-protect much more quickly and effectively than you can protect.  And, once they do, they will post it on the internet for other twenty year olds to find instantly.  You should rethink your strategy.