# how to protect pdf geneated from pdflatex and xelatex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf, viewers, drm

I've a `.tex` file. 
Most of the times, we use `pdflatex` to convert `.tex` to required `.pdf`. 
Some times, we use `xelatex` to convert `.tex` to required `.pdf`

These `pdfs` are editable using various tools; is there any way to disable edit in generated `pdf`?

Note: I'm looking for non editable PDF (not the one with password)

Comment: Would you like to share with us what you are trying to achieve? The answer may depend on why you want to limit editing (which is generally an inconvenience for your end user).

Comment: Adobe Acrobat has the means to lock a document.  Use "File->Properties" tab, and then set the "Security Method" (under the security tab) to password or certificate security.  You will get a menu allowing you to restrict editing (and many other features).  How to do this *inside* of LaTeX?  That I do not know.

Comment: Oh, BTW, and of course, if by chance you're trying to stop people copying, those without a secretary can just photograph the pages (or export them as images) and send them off to the google for character recognition.

Comment: pdftk is a possible solution, but it's not `TeX` - related

Comment: In many cases, at least, all somebody need to circumvent the 'security' is a PDF viewer which is not Adobe's. Or CUPS print-to-file functionality. Or... Generally, it is incredibly easy to circumvent this kind of thing.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text