# includegraphics, vector, make text unelectable

Tags: graphics

I am trying to display a vector image, and I've tried with both eps-format and pdf. The reason for choosing a vector image, is that I will be displaying the image at various sizes, and wish to keep them as sharp as possible and still use a small-sized image. The image is added nicely, and but since the image has some text in it I would, the text is selectable in the output-pdf. I would like the text not to be selectable. Any way to achieve this? Or is this just simply bad practice?
I have included the tiny .pdf with the logo in it here: [PDF-logo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rqg5ictp9lrznu/logo.pdf?dl=0)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
 \includegraphics{logo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11307/7883 should help you.  Your link is broken, however.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link. I've read through that, and they are mostly for making the whole output-pdf non-selectable. I would like my produced document to be selectable and everything, it's just the text in that image that I would like to be non-selectable. Until a better solution comes along, I think I will just convert the text in the image.

Comment: `pdf2ps` followed by `ps2pdf` will turn the text into a graphic, essentially. It will make the file bigger, though. Why the hang up about the text in the image being selectable?

Comment: Great, will look into it. It's not too important. Just my OCD fringing a little when I see that what I thought was an image, is selected as text. Probably doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Another way could be edit the pdf file with Inkscape and convert the text blocks in vectorial objects, and then save again as PDF.