# Randomising mapping to glyphs in pdfLateX / XeLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, characters, minionpro, mapping

I've noticed that when using the MinionPro package, some glyphs like ligatures and oldstyle figures would be mapped to another character.

For example, compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[opticals]{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
123 Th fj fi ffj
\end{document}
```

using pdfLaTeX yields a PDF document that looks correct 
[image]

but if copied, it actually yields other glyphs like `Ïth û ö`.

I realise that this could be solved using `glyphtounicode`, but I'm thinking of **how this property can be used to actually prevent plagiarism** if I make all the glyphs map to wrong characters.

How can I achieve this using either pdfLateX or XeLaTeX? Is it as simple as creating a randomised custom `glyphtounicode`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11310/181777 might be interessting

Comment: this one is even closer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127902/181777