# Error compile in tcolorbox with package polyglossia

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, polyglossia

Where is the error

```
\documentclass[a4paper, x11names]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse,listings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,arrows.meta,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,shapes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    %select languages & fonts ==================================

    \setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=algeria]{arabic}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}% Aljazeera

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,listing and text}
    This is a  example.
    \end{tcblisting}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: This is the error. `The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".` :)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75267/the-fontspec-package-requires-either-xetex-or-luatex-to-function or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71436/fontspec-luatex-error

Comment: As CroCo noted: The error seems to be the wrong engine and has nothing to do with `tcolorbox`

Comment: Please modify the title to reflect the real issue to overcome wrong results in search engines.