# Goudy Old Style for LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Is there any possibility to make use of the font "**Goudy Old Style**" in a LaTeX document? 
I haven't found it in the font packages.

Comment: If it is available as Open Type font, you can use it easily with XeLaTeX.

Comment: ... provided you only want to use it for text.  Using it for maths would be more complicated.

Comment: Maths is not required here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Remarks

I downloaded the font as `Goudy Old Style.ttf` and placed it in the same directory as my `.tex` file.

## Implementation

Typeset with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Goudy Old Style.ttf}
\begin{document}
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

1234567890
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: There's also a free OpenType version [here](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/sorts-mill-goudy), which appears to have old-style figures as default.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I almost accept it, but it is for XeTeX, not LaTeX. Since I never used something else than LaTeX, I am quite frightened to compile my documents with XeTeX from now on. Is there a LaTeX-fiddle-around solution or should I switch to XeTex just for this font?

Comment: @Martin: The difference between Xe(La)TeX and (pdf)LaTeX in terms of writing documents is pretty small, and could probably be summarized as “use `fontspec`, don't use `inputenc`”. See e.g. “[What is XeTeX exactly and why should I use it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/what-is-xetex-exactly-and-why-should-i-use-it?lq=1)”, and “[Using LuaTeX as a replacement for pdfTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32295/using-luatex-as-a-replacement-for-pdftex?lq=1)” which applies to XeTeX as well.

Comment: Just to be complete here for future readers and newbies to XeLaTeX: Also make bold and italic work: `\setmainfont[BoldFont=GOUDOSB.TTF,ItalicFont=GOUDOSI.TTF]{GOUDOS.TTF}`
by adressing installed system fonts.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the necessary files (incl. the pfb's) for use with LaTeX here (by default it uses old-style figures):
[Latex type 1 font packs](http://t1pack.wordpress.com/author/t1pack/)

Here is an example code:

```
documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{goudy}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Once upon a time, a long while ago, there were four little people whose names were   \textsc{Violet}, \textsc{Slingsby}, \textsc{Guy}, and \textsc{Lionel}, and they all   thought they should like to see the world. So they bought a large boat to sail quite round the world by sea, and then they were to come back on the other side by land. The boat was painted blue with green spots, and the sail was yellow with red stripes; and when they set off, they only took a small Cat to steer and look after the boat, besides an elderly Quangle-Wangle, who had to cook dinner and make the tea; for which purposes  they took a large kettle.

\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting document]

Installation of the font pack (a rar file): it suffices to unrar it, which gives you a ‘goudy’ directory, containing a dvips/, a fonts/ and a tex/ directories; these can be copied as they are in a local texmf directory.

However, you can make the following changes if you want a clean installation: the dvips directory contains only a dvips\config\pgy.map. Move pgy.map to fonts\map\dvips. In this same directory, you'll find a paj.map which seems to be there by error (it has nothing to see with Goudy) and can safely be deleted, as well as the dvips directory after you've moved pgy.map. Then copy the fonts/ and tex/ directories in the local texmf directory.

For further details, see the [Manual font installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

Comment: There's nothing obviously relevant at the page I get when I follow that link. (There is a further link to sky drive which I didn't explore much.) Those packs do not look entirely legal to me but perhaps I just have a suspicious mind and the author really does have permission to distribute e.g. Hoefler.

Comment: It's in sky drive. I do not know whether the pack is legal, but anyone who bought the fonts has there the necessary files for compiling with (pdf)latex – and I don't see why this usage should be illegal. But perhaps I'm very naive…

Comment: Oh, if it is just support files it is probably legal. I wasn't clear whether they were actually including type1 fonts as well (and wasn't inclined to investigate further just to find out). For Goudy Old Style I'm not sure what the licence says but I think there are free versions of this anyway. Just the Hoefler made me suspicious.

Comment: @Bernard: pfbs of commercial fonts are usually _not_ free to distribute.

Comment: -1 for not providing any hint how and where to copy all those pfb, sty etc files such that pdflatex will find them.

Comment: Some details for installing and using fonts.