# need .sty for all attempts to use Goudy Old Style

Tags: installing-fonts

I have tried the suggestions for using Goudy Old Style on this page:
[Goudy Old Style for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152822/goudy-old-style-for-latex)
but in all cases I get the log error: "*.sty not found". Can anyone advise how to generate the .sty file? The Sorts Mill Goudy package looks awesome, but has no .sty and I cannot figure how to create it.
Thanks.
Russ

Comment: The first answer there doesn't mention a `.sty` file. So I assume you are trying to use the skydrive stuff, which is probably either illegal or useless to you. It will be rather hard for anybody to help with this as you've given next to no information and are using something which requires downloading from a page which my browser won't even let me view, never mind download from. (My browser can be a bit paranoid, but not usually this much.)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of  info here. Platform is MAC OSX 10.11.15 running latest MacTex version, TexLive etc - all standard installation and default install options via gui.

Comment: I place the font in ~myhome/Library/texmf/tex/latex
where latex  is the root of other font folders I have placed and had success with Tex finding them (like garamondx).
The font and its site both reference an opensource license to use freely, so I dont *think* there's an issue there. 
What this font folder lacks - which fonts downloaded from Latex Font Catalogue do contain - is a fontname.sty file.
Every compiler both Xetex and XeLatex complain that no .sty file is found. So I am trying to find guidance if there is a way to create that .sty file.

Comment: Here is the contents of the font folder, OFLGoudyStM: images(directory), OFLGoudyStM-Italic.otf, OFLGoudyStM.otf, OFLGoudyStMTT-Italic.ttf, OFLGoudyStMTT.ttf, Open Font License FAQ.markdown, Open Font License.markdown, readme.markdown and some dirs with numerous Mac .plist file

Comment: Use `fontspec` with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. You don't need a style file. You will need to install the fonts for your OS (e.g. with Font Book). Or else you would probably need to specify the full path names. Fonts should not be installed under `tex/latex/`. Moreover, it is really, really, really bad to install fonts into your personal TEXMF tree. Unless you lack admin rights on your machine, there is no reason to do this. If you do lack admin rights, it is better to do without the extra fonts if you possibly can.

Comment: Please see my question and answer on the font installation issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i/255711#255711. `garamondx` should be installed with `getnonfreefonts-sys`. It will place some files under `tex/latex` in your local TEXMF tree (i.e. not your personal one), but not the fonts themselves.

Comment: OK thank you for the replies. I'll go back to the drawing board and use getnonfreefonts-sys for installing the fonts pulled from the Font Catalogue. Last question: is LuaLaTex or XeLatex capable of using any font in the Font Book, or just the system fonts? (My understanding is System fonts are only a subset in FontBook - other apps like MS Office could install their own (like Goudy Old Style !)

Comment: I am not sure. They don't need to be in `/System/...`. I think they would be fine in your home `Library`. But they might need to be under `/Library/...`. I'd be surprised if the latter were true, but I don't want to rule it out. I think if you just install them as you would any other font, it should be fine. It may be different from Office which used to install its fonts in a completely different place. I don't know if it still does this or not.

Comment: Make sure you read the end of my answer to the question I linked, where it explains what to do if you read the answer 'too late'. If you've ever run `updmap` or `getnonfreefonts` rather than the `-sys` versions, then you need to take some steps to undo the effects.