# How can I write Persian in TeXstudio?

Tags: packages, persian

I want to write some Persian text in Texstudio. Which package should I use? I've heard about `xepersian` but I don't know how to use it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xepersian} 
\settextfont{XB Roya} 
\begin{document}
 سلام! 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I guess, this has nothing to do with TeXStudio. Please show us something, you already have tried. We do not want to write everything from scratch. We don't know anything about your documentclass, how you compile it, and so on... Here are several threats on xepersian on this side. Please read them and tell us, what you don't understand. Did you run your code with XeLaTeX?

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Roya}
\begin{document}
سلام!
\end{document}

Comment: this is the code i wrote but an error occurs...what is xetex?

Comment: Are you sure you have that font properly installed?  I don’t have it, but your example works for me when I substitute IranNastaliq.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3393/7883 for your question, “What is xetex?”  Without `xetex`, your example cannot work.

Comment: See https://omidraha.com/en/latest/src/latex/tips.html#write-persian-in-latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Xepersian documents must be processed by xelatex. In TeXstudio choose Tools/Commands/XeLaTeX and then press F7 for viewing the output.

It is supposed that the XB Roya font which is mentioned in your example is installed in your system. X Series 2 fonts can be downloaded from [here](http://wiki.irmug.com/index.php/X_Series_2).

Comment: hi thanks for your answer.i dont find the "commands" under Tools??please help me

Comment: @ zahraesb In Options/Configure TeXstudio/Build/Meta Commands set XeLaTeX as default compiler.