# I can't run this latex script

Tags: texlive, xepersian

I've installed latex with `sudo apt install texlive-full` and `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-arabic` .
I'm using Texmaker.
But I can't run the script below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Titr}
\setlatintextfont{Lato Thin}

 
\begin{document}
\textbf{سلام لاتک! }

این یک نوشته‌ی آزمایشی است

\end{document}
```

the errors occurred :

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Titr" cannot be found.
! Font TU/Titr(0)/m/n/12=Titr/OT at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or i
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  "Can't run" isn't very informative.  Do you get an error?  What error?

Comment: @Teepeemm thanks!
yes I'll edit now,

Comment: Titr font isn't part of texlive but google suggests it may be downloaded from lots of places

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would you explain how can I install this font? I know it's easy to find in a google search but I have tried many times but failed.

Comment: just putting it in the same directory as your document should work, for example.

Comment: This may answer your question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186953/how-can-i-write-persian-in-texstudio