# Is LuaLaTeX our future?

Tags: luatex

I've read somewhere that LuaTeX is choosen to be mainstream for LaTeX development? Is it really true? [E-TEX: Guidelines for Future TEX Extensions -- revisited](http://latex-project.org/papers/tb106mittelbach-e-tex-revisited.pdf) says nothing about that. I mean where is it stated that  *Luatex was adopted by the pdfTeX team as a successor to pdftex and the development of pdftex is closed* as –@Alain Matthes writes in his comment?

Comment: I've thought about adding an answer, such as "LuaTeX is great" or "LaTeX3 is currently working much in the background and is already present on most of our TeXlive/MikTeX systems", but I find it hard to give a good answer, for I cannot see into the future.

Comment: @Patric, characterise the present state then.

Comment: You could ask this question in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41) instead. It can make a good discussion topic.

Comment: Actually pdftex is the mainstream. Luatex was adopted by the pdfTeX team as a successor to pdftex and the development of pdftex is closed. It's natural to declare  Luatex  the mainstream.

Comment: Perhaps this discussion on the [differences between luatex context and xetex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex) is relevant to you?