# XeTeX, LuaTeX: a good investment?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawbacks of XeTeX/LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex)

I'm only writing in English and French. In order to get the best appearance (ligatures, spacing between words and letters...), would it be a good investment to move from pdfTeX to XeTeX or LuaTeX?

Comment: Please see the related questions on the right (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex?rq=1, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex?rq=1, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30702/is-lualatex-our-future?rq=1) and then edit your question to clarify it; as it is it will likely be closed as not constructive.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Your question was closed because this topic has already been covered. We hope the linked questions help. Feel free to add specific questions in case you need details.