# Use biblatex and utf8

Tags: biblatex, unicode

For my thesis, I use biblatex for the bibliography.

As seen [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=623039), biblatex is not compatible, with `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`. It was reported as close but I still have the same problem with my version of bibtex (last one on archlinux [2011.24688-1](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-bibtexextra/)). I want to use the € symbol inside my report but it fails without utf8.

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'ucs'.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{document}
```

Any idea idea how to fix ?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{includes/mybib}{}

\begin{document}

X said Y \cite{bib1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the file mybib

```
@online { bib1,
       title = {Refrence title},
       author = {X},
       url = {http://site.com/y}}
```

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be handy here: my answer is something of a guess without it!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't use utf8x. Load the TS1-encoding e.g. through `textcomp` and if you don't like the euro you get with `textcomp` change the definition of `\texteuro`. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eurosans}

\begin{document}
€  \let\texteuro\euro €
\end{document}
```

Comment: `File 'eurosans.sty' not found. ^^M`

Answer (score 32):

The `utf8x` option for `inputenc` is (probably) the issue here. Try just

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and you should be fine (as detailed in the [`biblatex` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex)).

Answer (score 0):

As also explained in the biblatex documentation, you can use an TeX engine which is compatible with Unicode directly, like [XeTeX](http://www.luatex.org/roadmap.html#tbp) or [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org). For example XeTeX assumes the input is UTF-8 by default

If you use these, you don't need (and you should not use) the `inputenc` package

You can find more about the differences among these 3 in the [LuaTeX page](http://www.luatex.org/roadmap.html#tbp) or in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex/72#72) response