# Package BibLaTeX error: incompatible package 'ucs' \begin{document}

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm having the following code and I'm trying to compile my pdf. But I'm getting an error that says: `Package biblatex Error: incompatible package 'ucs' \begin{document}` .. my pdf compiles for some reason but the bibliography never appears...  why ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.5cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm,
bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\bibliography{ref} 

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{ref}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: an error about `ucs package and biblatex are incompatible` shows in the log file. According to BibLaTeX manual you must use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead.

Comment: see a similar answer to your question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49611/36131

Comment: if I use \usepackage[urf8]{inputenc} then I won't be able to write in greek right ?   So it's not very convinient...

Comment: the error has nothing to do with `inputenc`, but with incompatibility of `BibLaTeX` with it. Also, if `BibLaTeX` is to be used, then specify the style of the bibliography in the preamble. And since your purpose is to write Greek, just `\selectlanguage{greek}` for it precedes the default English.

Comment: how do I specify the bibliography in the preamble? My default language is going to be english and the secondary greek.. that's why I've specified it like this in the preamble

Comment: Stefanos this question had to do with BibLaTeX and utf8x.  Since you want the former, the latter must be replaced by utf8. Then remove `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` and add `\addbibresource{file.bib}` to the preamble. Then use `backend=biber` for example, as an option for `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}`, then remember to run biber or else it won't compile.