# Font Change Doesn't Show in TeXShop

Tags: fonts, texshop

I'm extremely new to TeX. I'm currently using TeXShop 3.26 on OSX Mavericks. I've located the font change menu under preferences, however, after choosing my desired font, the changes only show up on the editor and not the actual document after typesetting. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Long story short, remember that *all* information needed to typeset your document is in the text of your source file.  If you don't see a change in the actual *text*, your document hasn't changed.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/877597/1443496 and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts.  You might also want to take a look at [XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36) and the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.

Comment: The font used in the editor has no relation whatsoever with the font in the LaTeX output PDF file. In the TeXShop window you're just editing a text file. In order to get a different font than the default in the output, issue an appropriate `\usepackage` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try for example the following commands in the preamble :

```
\usepackage{times}
```

or

```
\usepackage{helvet}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use XeTeX, you can use something like this:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% the above line is TeXShop specific -- it will set
% the engine for you when you open the document

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

You can set the engine within the menu system with `Macros > Program > XeLaTeX`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the preferences font change menu is there only to change the font used to type your source-code in the editor, which has nothing to do with the actual font in the final document.
To use a (text) font in the final document, you have two ways for proceeding : if you compile with latex or pdflatex, you need to load a package that explains (pdf)latex how to use this font – or to create one yourself, and load it. Currently, there is a comparatively small number of fonts you can use this way, among which, URW Garamond no 8, BitStream Charter, Adobe Utopia, Minion Pro, Times, Palatino, kpfonts. The corresponding packages have support for maths.

The other way is to compile with xelatex or lualatex: you then have to load the fontspec package and set any chosen font, say Adobe Caslon Pro, in this way:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Caslon Pro}
```

You can use any font known to the system: you just have to give its name. Of course, you may have to settle some details such as using oldstyle or lining numbers, which ligatures you'll use, &c. Details are in fontspec documentation. Actually, fontspec works quite well with opentype fonts.

Notice however that it works only for text fonts. Also notice that you don't have to load the fontenc package, since it uses system fonts, nor inputenc, since it supposes your source code is utf8-encoded. By the way, I believe that TeXshop default encoding is still AppleRoman; if it's the case, you should change it to utf8.