# Using new fonts in TexLive

Tags: fonts, texlive

I'm sorry if this is a question already answered, but I could not find a good solution just browsing google. I use TexLive and I would very much like to use some new fonts (Georgia and Verdana). I'm regularly changing between both OS X and windows.

I cannot seem to find a good way to get these fonts installed, is there some easy way to get these fonts in use?

Thanks in advance : )

SOLUTION:

I ended up using xelatex, I worked very well without the need to install anyting new.

Comment: If you use `xelatex` or `lualatex` with the package `fontspec` then you have direct access to the system fonts.  See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36/15925

Answer (score 2):

Install and use the Verdana package: http://ctan.org/pkg/verdana

Install and use mathgifg package for Georgia: the http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg

To compile a file with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX takes much longer than with pdftex, so I stick to pdftex, regardless of any advantage of newer engines.

Comment: Compiling with `luatex` used to take much longer, especially in the case of long documents with fonts supporting many languages and more than one script (e.g., Brill): I could leave my desk and have dinner while waiting.  But things have become many times quicker, so that with big, multilingual documents, I don’t even have time to heat water for tea while waiting.

Comment: @Thérèse Oh, thank you for the hint. Last time I checked was certainly a year ago. I'll try again.

Comment: I've checked LuaTeX again. It takes at least five times longer than pdfTeX.