# Empty frames in beamer in case of RTL languages without tikz package, xelatex engine

Tags: beamer, xetex, right-to-left, bidi

I can not understand why all components of a beamer presentation are not showing (really empty frames) with this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\title{\textenglish{Title of presentation}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If we add `tikz` package we obtain output satisfactory, this happen only if we define an RTL (right to left ) language as main language.

When removing the sign `%` before `\usepackage{tikz}` we obtain

[image]

Could one explain why is this happening, thanks.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because versions (less than or equal to 18.3) of `bidi` package checked that if `pgf` package is loaded and then the `bidi` package would modify `pgfpicture` environment; this is what `tikzpicture` uses. However, `beamer` loads `pgfcore` package so the `bidi` package changes were not applied.

In version `18.4` of the `bidi` package, some improvements are made regarding the `pgf` and `tikz` packages; the `bidi` package now checks if the file `pgfcorescopes.code.tex` (where `pgfpicture` is defined) and changes the definition accordingly. So with your minimal example (without loading the `tikz` package):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\title{\textenglish{Title of presentation}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You get the following output:

> [image]

which is exactly identical to your own image (except the font).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case  I need only to update `bidi` package.

Comment: @salimbou: Yes, please do. Several issues regrading pgf/tikz/tcolorbox are fixed in the new version.