# How to enforce disabled protrusion for first line of paragraph

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, protrusion

My setup is LuaLaTex with `fontspec` and `microtype`.

I would like to overwrite the default protrusion settings of microtype for the font I am using.

As there are no font-specific defaults defined, I started off with copying the whole `\SetProtrusion` definition from `microtype.cfg` (designated with `name = default`) into my document's preamble.

**Outdated and incorrect description of the problem. See update below.**

However, I noticed that after copying, the first character of an indented paragraph gets out-kerned too; which is not the case if I rely on the default settings coming from microtype itself. This means, that for example every quote/dialogue gets out-kerned ("protrusioned?"), because these paragraphs start with a right-quote.

How does microtype turn off the protrusion for the first character in a paragraph? Can I copy this behaviour somehow, when I am defining a protrusion table myself?

**Update: reactions to the comments**

OK, I am having problems with creating a minimal working example. As in: I cannot reproduce the problem with a small example. I have been doing a little more debugging, and it is actually more subtle than I ever anticipated. Using `\strut` does not fix the problem.

The problem is as follows: I have a big body of text which is already typeset. I wanted to adjust some of the protrusion settings (I know, it should be done the other way around, first the settings, then the typesetting). For this, I copied the whole `\SetProtrusion` table from `mictrotype.cfg` into my preamble, without changing anything.

In around 2 per mille of the paragraph I get an underfull hbox, which is expected.

However, in 0.375 per mille (roughly 3 out of 8000) of the paragraphs, I get an overfull hbox! Some of the lines are re-flowed, after copying the protrusion table from the standard microtype environment into my document. I looked more closely and I cannot see any changes in protrusion in the document, so I cannot explain this change in spacing (yes, the now overfull lines are more densily spaced than beforehand).

I know, that without a working example this is hard to judge, if anybody has ideas, they are welcome, otherwise thank you for your attention!

**Update: I think I found it, but it's kinda crazy**

I played around with the protusion settings a little bit (based on the log file, I assumed that the default protrusion settings are used, probably I am mistaken!). One of the newly overfull lines is ending with a comma, and for commas there is an entry in the protrusion table: `{,}= { ,650}`. If I am not mistaken, this means, that the comma is margin-kerned with 65% of its own width. If I have this in the protrusion settings, then this line is re-flowed. If I remove this, then the line is not re-flowed, however, the comma is not out-kerned.

This means, that in the "real" settings which are used during typesetting, the protrusion for the comma is *less* than 650, as with 650 the first word of the next line ("he") is put into this line, otherwise an underfull would occur, because of spacing.

*I would close this as a PEBKAC:* the assumption that the standard protrusion setting is in effect was false.

Thank you all for being my [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)!

Comment: »Context is LuaLaTex with `fontspec` and `microtype`.«  No, see [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex)

Comment: @HenriMenke: sorry, I mean that my setup is. I will rephrase.

Comment: your question would be a lot easier to understand if you showed a small complete document, and the output that you with to get from that document. (in particular can you reproduce this with any standard font that people can test with)

Comment: If you begin each indented paragraph with `\strut` does that fix the problem? Note that `\strut` (as with most TeX commands) gobbles the space that immediately follows. If this works, it is not practical for a large number of manually-edited paragraphs, but it might help us to debug your problem.

Comment: What is “promill”? Is it something like “percent”, with 1000 instead of 100? Never heard that word before. I think you should be able to make an example by identifying a paragraph (or a couple of paragraphs) for which you have this problem, and cutting out all other paragraphs from the document. I hope there is nothing very “sensitive” in these paragraphs so you should be fine to share.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR sorry, in English it should be "per mille", cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_mille

And also, see the update in the post. Thank you for your suggestion, it is actually what I did, in the big document (I am still before my first coffee, and somehow couldn't reproduce it with replicating the section in another document).

Comment: it is hard to see why you can not make a reproducible example. Line breaking is specific to a paragraph so if you take a copy of your original document, delete everything except one bad paragraph, and ensure that `\hsize` for that paragraph in the new document is the same  as in the original document context, then the linebreaking will show the same behaviour.

Comment: Closed as requested. I just cannot edit the closing reason stated below the question, I hope it causes no confusion.