# content exceeded limit of the table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

Content exceeded limit of the row, when the content is long, my code is

```
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{15mm}|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{hola como estas, yo estoy aprendiendo este mundo bello de la herramienta latex} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User B} & %
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User C}\\
\cline{2-5}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value}  \\

\hline
% etc. ...
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

the result is:
[image]

**demo:**  https://es.sharelatex.com/project/5a3056532fa5c507d4467dc1

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). From what is shown one may suspect that you forgot to load the `multirow` package.

Comment: @marmot I have added the multirow library

Comment: Well, first of all, your document does not start with `\documentclass`. Second, there are two `\end{tabular}` commands. Third, even if one makes this code compilable, then there is no 3 appearing. Most importantly, what do you expect LaTeX to do with `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`? What are the hyphenation rules? If you specify them, the A's will no longer overshoot.

Comment: @marmot now the content excedeed to down

Comment: Well, if you bought a birds cage, would you complain that it doesn't fit a lion? No, you'd either shrink the lion (don't do that! ;-) or buy a bigger cage. Same here. Of course, the content has to fit the environment. You will always be able to create structures that do not fit a given content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use content which is breakable.  With the `multirow` package you have to make sure that the content fits in the space provided yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{15mm}|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{=}{This is some equally long content with the difference that it is actually breakable} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User B} & %
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{User C}\\
    \cline{2-5}
     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Value}  \\

    \hline
    % etc. ...
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise you could use ConTeXt.

```
\starttext

\startxtable
  \NC[ny=2] This is some equally long content with the difference that it is actually breakable \NC User B \NC User C \NR
                                                                                                \NC Value  \NC Value  \NR
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: how import the library of the ConTeXt?

Comment: @x-rw [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex)

Comment: what is the solution for you first example?