# Any idea how can I draw the skills for resume like this?

Tags: lists, cv

[image]How to draw skills like this in the resume ?

Comment: What does this question have to do with TeX/LaTeX?

Comment: What do these numbers even mean? You have a nice personality 57% of the time? You know 57% of all languages in the world?

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 17):

Here is the obligatory [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) solution, wrapped inside a custom `itemize` environment that is created with [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). The net result is that using the lines

```
\begin{achievements}
  \item[57]\textbf{Personality}\\Leadership, innovation
  \item[16]\textbf{Organisation}\\blah
\end{achievements}
```

you can produce:

[image]

Of course, you can customise the colours to your hearts content!

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}% only to force percentages to be integers
\usepackage{enumitem}

\let\realItem\item% save for later use
\newcommand\percentageItem[1][10]{%
  \realItem[\smash{\tikz[baseline]{%
    \node[minimum width=4em] at (0,0) {\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{#1}\%};
    \draw[thick,line width=1.5mm,Blue](90:5mm)
          arc [radius=5mm, start angle=90, delta angle=-#1*3.6];
    \draw[thick,line width=1.5mm,LightSteelBlue](90-#1*3.6:5mm)
          arc [radius=5mm, start angle=90-#1*3.6, end angle=-270];
    }}]%
}
\newlist{achievements}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[achievements]{
  before=\let\item\percentageItem,%make \item = \percentageItem
  leftmargin=*,
  label={},
  itemsep=3mm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{achievements}
  \item[57]\textbf{Personality}\\Leadership, innovation
  \item[16]\textbf{Organisation}\\blah
\end{achievements}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the color it is very nice.

Answer (score 8):

With ConTeXt MKIV and MetaFun.

```
\noheaderandfooterlines
\startuseMPgraphic{circle}{percent}
  interim linecap := butt;
  pen thick;
  thick := pencircle scaled 2pt ;
  path p, q;
  p := reverse (fullcircle scaled (2.5*BodyFontSize) rotated 90);
  q := (p cutafter point (arctime \MPvar{percent}/100*(arclength p) of p) of p);
  draw p withcolor \MPcolor{gray} withpen thick;
  draw q withpen thick;
  label("\MPvar{percent}\%", origin);
\stopuseMPgraphic

\setupxtable[skills][frame=off,columndistance=1em]
\setupxtable[skill:head][foregroundstyle=bold]
\setupxtable[skill:list][foregroundcolor=darkgray]

\starttext

\startxtable[skills]
  \NC[ny=2] \useMPgraphic{circle}{percent=57} \NC[skill:head] Personality \NR
                                              \NC[skill:list] Lazy        \NR
  \NC[ny=2] \useMPgraphic{circle}{percent=62} \NC[skill:head] Personality \NR
                                              \NC[skill:list] Lazy        \NR
  \NC[ny=2] \useMPgraphic{circle}{percent=10} \NC[skill:head] Personality \NR
                                              \NC[skill:list] Lazy        \NR
  \NC[ny=2] \useMPgraphic{circle}{percent=23} \NC[skill:head] Personality \NR
                                              \NC[skill:list] Lazy        \NR
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing your full code ?

Comment: @KastuvM.Tuladhar This is the full code.  It's [ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex), not LaTeX.

Comment: Nice. I might add this to the [visualcounter](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter) module...