# Tikzpicture as bullet in itemize

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize

Is it possible to use Tikz nodes as bullets inside `itemize` with Beamer? My very naive try doesn't work (obviously):

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\begin{tikzpicture}\node[draw,circle,minimum size=9mm] {x};\end{tikzpicture}] x
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. It is possible to use tikz inside an \item (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442257/any-idea-how-can-i-draw-the-skills-for-resume-like-this/442263#442263). Try adding `[fragile]` to the fame.

Comment: Additionally `[...[...]...]` is not a good idea, the parse does not know how to match the proper `[]`'s. So `\item[{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[draw,circle,minimum size=9mm] {x};\end{tikzpicture}}]` is better

Comment: You should put the tikzpicture in a `\mbox{...}`.

Comment: Indeed, I solved this by putting the whole `tikzpicture` in a `\newcommand`, but the solution by @javadr also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\tikz` instead of `\begin{tikzpicture}`, like below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  [\tikz{\node[draw,circle,minimum size=3mm] {x};}] test
        \item 
        \item 
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]