# For my CV, I need to put my skills in image form but it is giving errors

Tags: metadata, curve-class

I need to put my skills in image form in an Overleaf CV template but it is giving errors. I got the [Template from Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv). It compiled well but when I tried to integrate my skills in image form I received errors. Also, I found code to the image form at ([Any idea how can I draw the skills for resume like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442257/any-idea-how-can-i-draw-the-skills-for-resume-like-this)).

The image and the code are attached. Could anyone help me in solving the problem?

[image: This is the image form that I need to represent my skill]

That code is the `cv-llt.tex` (main):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This CV example/template is based on my own
% CV which I (lamely attempted) to clean up, so that
% it's less of an eyesore and easier for others to use.
%
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com)
% 13 May, 2020
%
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,english]{curve}

% Uncomment to enable Chinese; needs XeLaTeX
% \usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage{settings}

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec} 
  %% You can use \setmainfont etc; I'm just using these font packages here because they provide OpenType fonts for use by XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX anyway
  \usepackage[p,osf,swashQ]{cochineal}
  \usepackage[medium,bold]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl,scale=0.9]{zi4}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[p,osf,swashQ]{cochineal}
  \usepackage{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl,scale=0.9]{zi4}
\fi

%% Only needed if you want a Publication List
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

%% Specify your last name and first name (as given in the .bib) to automatically bold your own name in the publications list. One caveat: You need to write \bibnamedelima where there's a space in your name for this to work properly for now...
\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}
% \myname{d'Andrimont}{Raphaël}

% Change the page margins if you want
% \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

% Change the colours if you want
% \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{00FFFF}
% \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{0000CC}

% Change the item prefix marker if you want
% \prefixmarker{$\diamond$}

%% Photo is only shown if "fullonly" is included
\includecomment{fullonly}
% \excludecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Your Name Here, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelope[regular]}{\texttt{example@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@example}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://example.example.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedin}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/example/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
%\photo[r]{photo}
\photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't have any publications; delete this line.
%% Sometimes when a section can't be nicely modelled with the \entry[]... mechanism; hack our own and use \input NOT \makerubric

\makerubric{skills}

\end{document}
```

That code is the `settings.sty` (style):

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[longtable]
\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't need biblatex; delete this line.
\RequirePackage[bibstyle=apa6,sorting=ymdnt,uniquename=init,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
%% Added 17 Jan 2018 from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140641/226 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46879/226
\DeclareSortingTemplate{ymdnt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{sortyear}
    \field[strside=left,strwidth=4]{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{00}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}
   
\newcounter{bibitem}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}

% \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2.5em}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\xpretofieldformat{doi}
  {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\scriptsize\faLink}}
  {}{}
\xpretofieldformat{url}
  {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\scriptsize\faLink}}
  {}{}

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
\def\@@rubrichead#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
  \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
  \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace\rubricspace%
}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
( type=book or type=incollection )
}

\newcommand{\myname}[2]{%
   \def\@mylastname{#1}%
   \def\@myfirstname{#2}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}%
}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

That code is the `skills.tex`:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF8
%!TEX root =cv-llt.tex

\begin{rubric}{Skills}
\noentry{2014 -- 2015}
\entry*[Languages]
    Strong reading, writing and speaking competencies for English, Mandarin Chinese, Bahasa Malaysia.
\entry*[Coding\hfill]
    Java, \smallcaps{PHP}, Python, R, \smallcaps{SQL, XML/XSL}, \LaTeX, \ldots
\entry*[Databases]
    My\smallcaps{SQL}, Postgre\smallcaps{SQL}, \smallcaps{HSQL}, \smallcaps{SQL}ite, LotusNotes.
\entry*[Web Dev]
    \textsc{Html, css}, JavaScript, Apache Web Server, Tomcat Web Server.
\entry*[Misc.]
    Academic research, teaching, training, consultation, \LaTeX\ typesetting and publishing.
\end{rubric}
```

That code is the `skills.tex`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}% only to force percentages to be integers
\usepackage{enumitem}

\let\realItem\item% save for later use
\newcommand\percentageItem[1][10]{%
  \realItem[\smash{\tikz[baseline]{%
    \node[minimum width=4em] at (0,0) {\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{#1}\%};
    \draw[thick,line width=1.5mm,Blue](90:5mm)
          arc [radius=5mm, start angle=90, delta angle=-#1*3.6];
    \draw[thick,line width=1.5mm,LightSteelBlue](90-#1*3.6:5mm)
          arc [radius=5mm, start angle=90-#1*3.6, end angle=-270];
    }}]%
}
\newlist{achievements}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[achievements]{
  before=\let\item\percentageItem,%make \item = \percentageItem
  leftmargin=*,
  label={},
  itemsep=3mm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{achievements}
  \item[57]\textbf{Personality}\\Leadership, innovation
  \item[16]\textbf{Organisation}\\blah
\end{achievements}

\end{document}

% That code the skills in image form.tex
```

Detailed code can be found at ( https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv) and ([Any idea how can I draw the skills for resume like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442257/any-idea-how-can-i-draw-the-skills-for-resume-like-this)).

Comment: You tagged your question with `moderncv` and `awesome-cv`, but it seems you are using `curve`. Please clarify which class you use for your cv ...

Comment: Do you have to rank your skills like this, or do you just want to? I personally think it's a weird thing to rank your personality in percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert the new code in the proper place.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,english]{curve}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< before \usepackage{settings}
\usepackage{siunitx}% only to force percentages to be integers

\newcommand{\description}{}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\realItem\item% save for later use
\newcommand\percentageItem[1][10]{%
    \realItem[\smash{\tikz[baseline]{%
            \node[minimum width=4em] at (0,0) {\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{#1}\%};
            \draw[thick,line width=1.5mm,Blue](90:5mm)
            arc [radius=5mm, start angle=90, delta angle=-#1*3.6];
            \draw[thick,line width=1.5mm,LightSteelBlue](90-#1*3.6:5mm)
            arc [radius=5mm, start angle=90-#1*3.6, end angle=-270];
    }}]%
}

\newlist{achievements}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[achievements]{
    before=\let\item\percentageItem,%make \item = \percentageItem
    leftmargin=*,
    label={},
    itemsep=3mm,
    labelindent=40pt,   
}

\usepackage{settings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % after \usepackage{settings} <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec} 
  %% You can use \setmainfont etc; I'm just using these font packages here because they provide OpenType fonts for use by XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX anyway
  \usepackage[p,osf,swashQ]{cochineal}
  \usepackage[medium,bold]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl,scale=0.9]{zi4}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[p,osf,swashQ]{cochineal}
  \usepackage{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl,scale=0.9]{zi4}
\fi

%% Only needed if you want a Publication List
%\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}

\includecomment{fullonly}

\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Your Name Here, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelope[regular]}{\texttt{example@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@example}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://example.example.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedin}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/example/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
\photo[r]{photo}
\photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}


\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

\makerubric{employment}
\makerubric{education}

\makerubric{skills}
\begin{achievements}
    \item[57]\textbf{Personality}\\Leadership, innovation
    \item[16]\textbf{Organisation}\\blah
\end{achievements}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Best regards.