# LaTeX font/symbols rendering detailed information

Tags: fontspec, rendering

For a project I'm doing I need to render math equations in a 3D environment (LaTex style math symbols), and I want to use vector fonts instead bitmaps. I want to know where to get detailed information about how LaTex load and render the fonts, has been difficult to get the information and I'm quite lost on this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have tagged this fontspec so are you using luatex or xetex? but latex (classically) knows essentially nothing about the fonts, it just uses the font metrics ie height depth and width of each character.

Comment: I suspected that, now, I read this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex and now I have a better idea what to look for, as I mention I'm quite new on this, and seems like fonts in detail are a whole world to discover.